# Django: Display a model and a count of how often another model uses it

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I am creating a TODO list that categorizes tasks by their status.  IE: Waiting, Today, Tomorrow, Scheduled.  My models look something like:

```
class Status(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=32)

class Task(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status, default=1)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True)
    completed = models.BooleanField()
```

I want to create a navigation list that displays all of the statuses (which is simple) but also the count of how many tasks are assigned to each (that is where I am stuck).

> Waiting(1)
>   Today(3)
>   Tomorrow(1)
>   Scheduled (0)

It needs to be able to produce the status even if the count is 0.  It's a navigational list and I want the user to be able to see where they can put a task.

```
Status.objects.all()
```

Above will get me my list but I don't know how to get the count of tasks.  I figure I have to work in reverse, pull a list of tasks and group them by my Status model but I am at a loss on how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django's [aggregation features](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset) can do this quite simply.

```
from django.db.models import Count
statuses = Status.objects.all().annotate(Count('task'))
```

Now each item in `statuses` has an attribute `task__count` which is the number of tasks related to that status.

Comment: This was exactly what I didn't and I'm gonna accept it as soon as I can but let me ask one last follow up.  What if I wanted to filter by users which only exists in the Task model?

Comment: The page I linked to should have all the relevant information about combining filtering with aggregations. If you have another specific problem, please ask a new question.